# Create array and append key and value in each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a array and then to insert values for each key (key should be the value from each). But seems to not working. This is my code.

```
@options = %w(Services Resources)
@images  = []
@options.each do |value|
    @images[value] << Media::Image.where(type: "Media::#{value.singularize}Image")
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@images` is an array so referencing an element in it should be `@images[Integer]` and `value` is a string (in the first iteration it's "Services" and in the second "Resources"). Instead, what would work for you is `Hash`:

```
@options = %w(Services Resources)
@images  = {}
@options.each do |value|
    @images[value] = Media::Image.where(type: "Media::#    {value.singularize}Image")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

@images is a Array, Array can not use as a Hash.
Maybe you want create a Hash like this

`@images = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}`

Comment: It should be `@images = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}` if the `<<` operator is used.